# Toggle between mouseup and mousedown event

Tags: jquery

The "mousedown" event works fine whereas "mouseup" event doesn't. How the "mouseup" event call the "down()" recursively ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function fly(){
        $("img").animate({top :'-=50px',left:'+=50px'},1000);
    }
    function down(){
        $("img").animate({top:'+=50px',left:'+=50px'},1000);
    }

    $( "button" ).mouseup(function() {
        setInterval(down,1000)
    }).mousedown(function() {
        setInterval(fly,1000)
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not clearing the intervals ever. Both functions will continue to be called. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear your intervals, otherwise the fly and down functions won't be stopped calling and will also be called by multiple instances of your intervals. That is also why it is good practice to make sure the interval you are trying to create is cleared.

You also probably want the mouseup interval on the body of your document. Otherwise the mouseup is not registered when the person moves his mouse away from the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var downInterval, upinterval;

    function fly(){
        $("img").animate({top :'-=50px',left:'+=50px'},1000);
    }
    function down(){
        $("img").animate({top:'+=50px',left:'+=50px'},1000);
    }

    $( "button" ).mousedown(function() {
        clearInterval(downInterval);
        clearInterval(upInterval);
        downInterval = setInterval(fly,1000);
    });

    $( "body" ).mouseup(function() {
        clearInterval(upInterval);
        clearInterval(downInterval);
        upInterval = setInterval(down,1000);

    });
});
```